# PHP contact form with Freehostia

Tags: php, forms, email

I cannot get this form to send if I use anything other than `$from = 'From: . $email';`. If I change it to anything else, it will not send. When it does send with this information, it comes in from `.$email@mbox.freehostia.com`.

What I would prefer is have the from email address be the email that was submitted in the form, so the receiver can respond without having to create a new email. I've searched everything and can't find an answer to this specific issue.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: . $email';
$to = 'info@resourcedmichigan.com';
$subject = 'ResourcED Career Submission';

$body = "From: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone Number: $phone\nMessage: $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        include("inc/header.php");
        echo '<div class="container"><div class="spacer-top"><h3>Thank you for your interest in ResourcED! We will be in contact with you soon!</h3></div></div>';
        include("inc/footer.php");
    } else {
        echo '<div class="container"><h3>Something went wrong. Go back and try again!</h3></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So what do you want to appear in your From? `From: president@whitehouse.gov`?

Comment: `$from = 'From: ' . $email;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables will not be interpolated inside of single quotes and the concatenation operator is unnecessary.

```
$from = 'From: . $email';
```

should be

```
$from = "From: $email";
```

or

```
$from = 'From: ' . $email;
```

Comment: Good grief. It was that simple. Thanks for the clarification John!